# Is there a semantic query tool for java/java IDEs?

Tags: java, eclipse, search, ide, semantics

For analyzing/refactoring tasks, I need some kind of semantic query tool (or eclipse plugin) for java to answer questions like:

> Which classes call the equals() method
>   of classes which reside in a package
>   which name matches a specific pattern?
>   
> (or even more complex questions)

Are there some tools for these kind of jobs?

Comment: You don't need a _semantic query tool_ for this. Indeed, I believe you should remove the `semantic` tag from your question. What you might need is a java dependency analyzer: googling that, [Dependency Finder](http://depfind.sourceforge.net/) seems a candidate.

Answer (score 0):

you can try and use the twouse plugin ,sparqlas will provide you the query support....